# Are these instrumental variables valid for our research study?

Tags: instrumental-variables

In our research we're conducting now, the dependent variables are well-being (self-esteem, self-worth, and mental health), our independent variables are the social media use (number of social media accounts, time spent using social media, amount of followings). We're supposed to have self-rated time, by rating how much time they spend on social media (not enough to too much, enjoyment, and influence (positive or negative) as the instrumental variables. How does the instrumental variables relate to the dependent variables?

Comment: What exactly do you ask? Are these variables well suited for modelling the well-being?

Comment: Yes @AlexeyBurnakov

Comment: Before trying them out it is hard to say of they are good explanatory features.

Comment: I don't actually know how to perform ivregress. I don't know which will be the dependent and which will be the endogenous variables

Comment: Now I dont follow you.

Comment: I mean, I don't know which will be the endogenous variable for my study.

Comment: I see now. It seems an intuition guessing right now. Why do you want to determine possible endogeneous prior to study?

Comment: I don't actually remember, but I think it was because the well-being might be affected by other things (maybe someone just died in their family), and the statistician we consulted said that we should add those 3 questions and use it as IVs for our study.

Answer (score 1):

Self-rated time spent on social media, enjoyment of social media, and perceived influence of social media are not instrumental variables in the common usage of that term.  An instrumental variable is one that a) exerts a causal effect on another predictor and b) exerts a causal effect on a dependent variable *only through that predictor*.  (In a regression model, the instrumental variable would be uncorrelated with the residuals [errors]).

In your scheme, self-rated time spent on social media, rather than being a cause of social media use, is another indicator of the same thing.  Enjoyment, rather than being strictly a cause of social media use, may (perhaps also) be a by-product of it; the causal arrow might run in either direction, or both. And the same could be said for perceived influence.

In your research, an instrumental variable might be something like amount of time with access to the internet, or amount of leisure time available.